# Issue with maven-style jenkins build/test on Cloudbees (cannot be reproduced on local Jenkins)

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, jenkins, cloudbees

I am new to Cloudbees and I noticed that **the very same tests that run smoothly on my local Jenkins are actually in error on Cloudbees's Jenkins**...

Basically, all **unit tests based on Mockito try to use Hibernate/Persistence** resulting in this exception:

```
Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
```

Tests that pass on my local machine are in error on Cloudbees...

*I am not sure why. Can anyone please help?*

**edit**: Full stack trace from Jenkins:

```
Tests in error: 
  modifyChildminderAdvertisementShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.advertisement.AdvertisementManagementTest)
  shouldContainCorrectNumberOfDayToTimeSlots(com.bignibou.tests.service.advertisement.RegularDayToTimeSlotsTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  shouldNotContainSaturdayNorSunday(com.bignibou.tests.service.advertisement.RegularDayToTimeSlotsTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  shouldNotContainEveningNorNighttime(com.bignibou.tests.service.advertisement.RegularDayToTimeSlotsTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  signupMemberShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  signupMemberShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfAddressRefenceIsEmpty(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  activateMemberShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfTokenIsEmpty(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  signupMemberShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfAddressRefenceIsNull(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  activateMemberShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfTokenIsNull(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  activateMemberShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  activateMemberShouldThrowInvalidTokenExceptionIfTokenIsInvalid(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<com.bignibou.InvalidTokenException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  signupMemberShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfMemberIsNull(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  signupMemberShouldRethrowMailerExceptionIfMessagingExceptionIsThrown(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<com.bignibou.MailerException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  activateMemberShouldThrowMailerExceptionIfMessagingExceptionIsThrown(com.bignibou.tests.service.signup.SignupServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<com.bignibou.MailerException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  resendActivationEmailShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  sendPasswordResetInfoShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  modifyEmailShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfMemberArgumentIsNull(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  resendActivationEmailShouldThrowInvalidTokenException(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<com.bignibou.InvalidTokenException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  modifyEmailShouldSetRelevantPropertiesToMember(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  emailShouldNotBeAvailable(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  activateEmailShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  shouldActivateEmail(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  modifyEmailShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfEmailArgumentIsEmpty(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  activateEmailShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfTokenArgumentIsNull(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  modifyEmailShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  emailShouldBeAvailable(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  modifyAddressShouldAllowMemberWithNoAddress(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  modifyPasswordShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  shouldThrowMailerException(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<com.bignibou.MailerException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  sendPasswordResetInfoShouldNotAllowInexistentEmail(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  shouldThrowInvalidTokenException(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<com.bignibou.InvalidTokenException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  saveAddressFromReferenceShouldHaveNormalInteractions(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
  modifyEmailShouldThrowIllegalArgumentExceptionIfEmailArgumentIsNull(com.bignibou.tests.service.preference.PreferenceServiceTest): Unexpected exception, expected<java.lang.IllegalArgumentException> but was<org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException>
  testPerformChildminderAdvertisementSearch(com.bignibou.tests.repository.advertisement.ChildminderAdvertisementIntegrationTest): Failed to load ApplicationContext
  shouldAllow(com.bignibou.tests.controller.advertisement.AdvertisementControllerTest): Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
  shouldNotAllow(com.bignibou.tests.controller.advertisement.AdvertisementControllerTest): Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tests run: 55, Failures: 8, Errors: 36, Skipped: 1
```

Comment: Add some context/detail to your question, otherwise it'll be difficult to help. Are you running an embedded database as part of the tests or using an external one?

Comment: Hi Jukka! For the integration tests I use HSQLDB but what puzzles me is that all tests (even unit tests that do not touch the db) are in error with the above hibernate error... What contextual info can I provide?

Comment: Maybe you're creating unnecessary transactions then. Any chance your test/implementation CLASSES are annotated with @Transactional? Show one of the test classes and classes under test as an example. Also posting the test spring config would help.

Comment: Many of my classes are indeed annotated with @Transactional but the interrogation really is about the different outcome of tests from my local Jenkins and Cloudbees' Jenkins...

Comment: Yea, so spring tries to start a transaction for each test method, which fails because it can't get a DB connection to HSQLDB. Try and dig deeper into what is causing this. Perhaps HSQLDB is not fired up properly. Post the relevant Spring configs and have Jenkins/Maven log a bit more.